# RabbitMQ: How can i create a synchronised Cluster

Tags: synchronization, cluster-computing, rabbitmq, high-availability

i have a RabbitMQ Cluster(version 3.0.1) with 3 nodes. I want, that my Queue is everytime on all 3 nodes available.
I create the cluster like this:

node1: 
node2: rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@node1
node3: rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@node1

After this, i set the following Policy:

Pattern:    **^(?!amq.).***
Definition: **ha-mode: all**

If i start now my 3 nodes and write somethink in 1 of my node, then i have it on all 3 and it works. But if the connection to 1 of the nodes dies and the node is comming back after a while, this node is not synchronised any more with the other nodes.
How can i resolve this? I want, that all nodes are every time synchronised, even after a downtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now with version 3.1.x there is an option ha-sync-mode which could be set to automatic, which solves your problem:

> Queues can be set to automatically synchronise by setting the
>   ha-sync-mode policy key to automatic. ha-sync-mode can also be set to
>   manual. If it is not set then manual is assumed.

Check http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Bad news for you sorry, but this is unsupported. When a new node joins a cluster it doesn't receive any of the existing messages.

From **Unsynchronised Slaves** http://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html:

> A node may join a cluster at any time. Depending on the configuration of a queue, when a node joins a cluster, queues may add a slave on the new node. At this point, the new slave will be empty: it will not contain any existing contents of the queue, and currently, there is no synchronisation protocol. Such a slave will receive new messages published to the queue, and thus over time will accurately represent the tail of the mirrored-queue.

**UPDATE:**

The answer applies to 2.8.x versions of RabbitMQ

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to remedy the problem by editing rabbitmq-server init.d script (/etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server).

Adding the following line after a successful start (in the **rabbitmq_start** function) will cause a newly joined member to synchronize all queues:

```
$CONTROL list_queues | cut -f1 | tail -n +2 | head -n -1 | xargs -n 1 $CONTROL sync_queue > /dev/null
```

Even though it's not the cleanest solution, it is still a solution. Not a big fan of modifying distribution files.